# Magento 1.9 SOAP API error forbidden

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I have been getting a "Forbidden" error when trying to make specific api calls. The API login and session retrieval work fine, but when I call salesOrderInfo or storesList functions I get that exception error. This is working on other magento installations on the same server. I have tried resetting the magento permissions with 664 on all files and 755 on all folders and 777 on mage folder.  Here is my code:

```
    try{
        $soap = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'SoapClient: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    try{
        $sessionId = $soap->login($api_user, $'api_key);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'soap login: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $filter = array('complex_filter'=> array(
        array(
            'key' => 'CREATED_AT',
            'value' => array('key' => 'from', 'value' => $minDate)
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'created_at',
            'value' => array('key' => 'to', 'value' => $maxDate)
        )            )
    );

    try{
        $ordersResult = $soap->salesOrderList($sessionId, $filter);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'salesOrderList: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    foreach($ordersResult as $order){
        //get order details
        try{
            $orders[] = $soap->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, $order->increment_id);
        }catch(\Exception  $e){
            echo 'salesOrderInfo: '. $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
        }
        //get store name for filtering
        $storeName[] = explode("\n", $order->store_name);
        $count++;
    }

    try{
        $stores = $soap->storeList($sessionId);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'storeList: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

After a bit more testing I noticed that it will only let me make 1 api call before giving forbidden error. I am not sure why that is, but I feel like it is important.

Comment: If you used soap v2  version then please used "http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" Url for calling  and check. If still have issue then please check soap user permission.

Comment: I know that the URL is correct because it is working with other magento installation on the same server. If I change it to what you suggested I get an error saying: "failed to load external entity "http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl". The user I setup should have all permissions. I set the Resource Access to be All. Any other ideas on what could be causing this?